# Reference-request to proof of H$^2(\Gamma, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) = 0$.

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, homology-cohomology

Does anyone maybe have a reference to a proof of the following theorem by Tate?

> Let $\Gamma$ be he absolute Galois group of the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> Then the second cohomology group H$^2(\Gamma, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is trivial.

I can't find it on the internet/books unfortunately.. any clue would be greatly appreciated!

Kinds regards

Comment: See this link and answer. Kind regards http://mathoverflow.net/questions/248607/reference-request-to-proof-that-h2-gamma-mathbbq-mathbbz-0#248607

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been answered at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/248607/reference-request-to-proof-that-h2-gamma-mathbbq-mathbbz-0

Comment: I have no problem with that! But maybe it is good to keep the link to the MO question for future visitors?

Comment: Yes of course, I didn't mean to _delete_ this good question, but just to close it because it has an accepted answer on MO.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments above, according to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248607/reference-request-to-proof-that-h2-gamma-mathbbq-mathbbz-0#248607) answer by Rene on MathOverflow:

> By the Galois cohomology long exact sequence, this is isomorphic to $H^3(\Gamma,\Bbb{Z})$, and the vanishing of this is Chapter I, Corollary 4.17 in Milne's *Arithmetic Duality Theorems*.